# Are questions regarding medical office administration on topic?

Tags: discussion

I have some questions about medical scheduling and office administration.

though not directly related to the medical sciences its related to its practice. Are such questions on topic?

Comment: +1 for asking before posting.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, no. If you look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you won't find any category that would include office administration. Those categories are:

> - Environmental or nutritional factors that affect health
> - The ways that diseases and injuries affect people
> - The health effects of processes such as pregnancy and aging
> - Medications and other interventions that are used to treat diseases

However, that section hasn't been updated to reflect the site's new scope yet, so let's take a look at the [new scope](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/907/805) as discussed in meta. Those categories are:

> - clinical guidelines
> - disease prevention and management
> - human physiology and pathophysiology
> - pharmacology
> - diagnostic and prognostic methods
> - public health
> - research

Again, no category encompasses office administration unless the question somehow fell under disease prevention and management or public health. So I'm afraid such questions would most likely be off topic under either old or new scope.

EDIT: I should add that I was going to edit the section on what's on topic today, so when you read this go by the text I quoted here, not what you find at the help section link.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I work at a clinic and have run into some issues concerning ethics and scheduling (i.e should younger patients be put in before older ones due to the fact that older patients take longer ect.) as well as issues with developing policy with managing visibly sick patients who walk in and end up sitting in a waiting room with (mostly) healthy pts coming in for non-treatment based stuff.

Comment: @EconJohn I can see some valid questions there. In particular, medical ethics and patient health concerns are likely on topic. I think all you can do is look at the _new_ scope guidelines as found in the help section (or this answer) and if you think your question fits, go ahead and post it. Worst case, it gets closed or edited to comply.

Comment: Thank you Carey!